# How to integrate django with WindowsServer 2012?

Tags: python, django, iis, wsgi, isapi

I have a Python3 website on IIS8 server and WindowsServer2012 and would like to add django to it. I have started learning django and made some small examplaes on my localhost and now want to integrate django into the IIS.

It is important to note that I just want to see that it works on my IIS and then turn it off, so that I can move all the site to django on localhost, while the current site is still functioning correctly.

I got confused regarding different ways. Where would be a good starting point for this integration (note, this is Windows Server 2012)?

Comment: Have you tried googling this? "django on iis" returns a lot of tutorials...

Comment: Yes. There are many, but I got lost with all the terms. In addition, some are for other virsions of IIS etc... couldnt find anything that fits. I am running IIS8 and WindowsServer2012 and the ones I found dont seem to be correct

Comment: Please check this link for django with windows server 2012 iis               http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html